# How can I prevent a line break at an SVG icon?

Tags: html, css, svg

In an HTML document, suppose I have something like a link that starts after another non-whitespace character, e.g.

```css
p {
  max-width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text that includes a link (<a href="https://example.com">example</a>)</p>
```

If the viewport width is such that the line has to break in the middle of the first word of the link text, then the preceding character (the opening parenthesis, in this case) "sticks" to the link, i.e. the standard layout algorithm breaks the line at the closest preceding whitespace.

However, if I want to insert an SVG icon at the start of the `a` element:

```css
p {
  max-width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text that includes a link (<a href="https://example.com"><svg style="height: 1em; color: green;" viewbox="0 0 10 10" fill="currentColor"><circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" /></svg>example</a>)</p>
```

Then the line is now allowed to break either side of the SVG.

### Question

Is there any way to make the layout engine treat the svg the same as it would normal text characters, so that the open parenthesis still "sticks" to the link text?

I can't make the whole paragraph or the whole link `white-space: nowrap` - I *want* the text to be able to wrap normally both within and outside the link, I just need it *not* to break around the `<svg>` (unless the link as a whole is preceded by whitespace).  Basically I want to be able to insert an icon at the start of the link without interfering with the normal text layout behaviour, as if the icon were just another character with all the same Unicode properties as the first character of the existing link text.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to simulate characters for your SVG using pure CSS (the `::first-letter` pseudo-element can be an option).

But I think you won't achieve the exact behavior of a standard character.

Tanishq's response works, but for example, if the parenthesis were before the image as it was in your initial example, not after, the parenthesis and the image would be separated onto different lines.

If you truly want character-like behavior, personally, I would turn to a [Dingbat typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dingbat).

You can certainly create your own Dingbat typography to embed a set of SVG icons and use them as you wish in the characters flow (it's the same principle as Google Material Icon).

For example, [Fontello](https://fontello.com/) website allows you to create your own typography in a few clicks.

Comment: This is the approach I've gone for in the end, I'm actually using Material Icons so I've just been able to switch from embedding the SVGs to using ligatures from the published icon font, so the layout engine just sees the characters `check_circle` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your best bet is to add the svg icon as a background image.

```css
p {
  width: 140px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

a {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 10 10' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Ccircle cx='5' cy='5' r='5' fill='green' /%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A") 0 0 / contain no-repeat;
  padding-left: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text that includes a link (<a href="https://example.com">example</a>)</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, this is probably the cleanest approach overall.  I couldn't use it in my project as there are cases where I need to add multiple separate icons to the start of the link, but I'll definitely bear it in mind for simpler cases in future.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution for you which required 2 basic changes

1. Convert the SVG to a .svg image URL.
2. Add a `::before` to the anchor tag and add the SVG to its `content`

Example:

```css
p {
  max-width: 140px;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.a::before {
  content: url('https://img.cdn4dd.com/s/media/photosV2/1954ba82-d91f-43a2-8838-767fd2ad386f-retina-large.svg');
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is some text that includes a link

  <a class="a" href="https://example.com">
    <span>
      &#40;example&#41;
    </span>
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Your example has the parenthesis _inside_ the `<a>` rather than before it, I tried playing with your solution putting the `(` immediately before the opening `<a>` tag and removing all the whitespace within the `a` and the `span`, but that seems to get back to the same problem I had originally with the line break going between the `(` and the image.

Answer (score -2):

I don't 100% understand what you are after.

`<nobr>` can keep content together:

```css
p {
  width: 140px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text that includes a link 
  <nobr>(
    <a href="https://example.com">
      <svg style="height: 1em; color: green;" viewbox="0 0 10 10" fill="currentColor"><circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" /></svg>example example example example example 
    </nobr>
  </a>)</p>
```

Comment: I made a slight adjustment to your demo to show the problem. You've proposed an alternative to `nowrap` that has the same deficiency.